# Как написать:

Tags: орфография

Вопрос:1. Ударение: деньгами или деньгами -  на какой слог? 2.Вживую - пишу слитно, компьютер подчеркивает-неправильно, всю жизнь писала слитно, может, правила изменились?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Литературная норма: деньгАм, деньгАми, о деньгАх.
Вариант дЕньгам, дЕньгами, о дЕньгах в некоторых словарях рассматривается как допустимый, однако устаревающий.

Ударение на первом слоге сохраняется в поговорке не в дЕньгах счастье, а также в названии пьесы А. Н. Островского «Бешеные деньги»: в «Бешеных дЕньгах» А. Островского.

Вживую - верно, если наречие (как?), слитно.Компьютер не различает совпадающие формы (в живую рыбу - разговаривал вживую)

Comment: "Компьютер" - слишком обобщённое понятие.  
Нужно указывать, какая именно компьютерная программа.  
Ворд прекрасно кушает "вживую", онлайн-проверка браузера FireFox этого слова не знает...   
Разные словари у этих программ.